# How to get Number of profile updates in Last 3 Months in FB using FB javascript SDK through FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way to get Number of profile updates in Last 3 Months in FB using FB javascript SDK through FB.api()?

I've set up login with Facebook and made necessary connections.

Now I need to get Number of profile updates in Last 3 Months using FQL Query.

Comment: That's not possible via FQL - you only get `profile_update_time`, and only if the last update is no longer than 3 days ago. _Server-side_ you could try with realtime updates to get notified whenever a change occurs, and then count those times yourself.

Comment: Thanks CBore. Now I can shut my client's mouth.